# modalinstance inject view model to update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Modal popups to list out accounts details (accno and name). once row is selected from list view model variable(vm.vismaDebitAccount) need to update which is dynamic. In actual scenario popup will be open on textbox onclick and once row is selected from popup relevant textbox text should be update with account name. The view model variable(a particular textbox binding) should be able to inject to modalinstance result without hard cord things.

Here is my code.

my problem is why vm.vismaDebitAccount is not getting update? Please help me.

Here is the place on UI binding

```html
 <tr ng-repeat="accEntry in vm.vismaAccEntries">
            <td>{{accEntry.invoiceNo}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model='accEntry.debitAccNo' required name="field" ng-click="vm.openVismaAccModal('debit')" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model='accEntry.debitVat' required name="field" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model='accEntry.creditAccNo' required name="field" ng-click="vm.openVismaAccModal('credit')"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model='accEntry.creditVat' required name="field" /></td>
            <td>{{accEntry.amount}}</td>
            <td>{{accEntry.voucherDate}}</td>
            <td>{{accEntry.dueDate}}</td>
```

```js
app.controller('invoiceCodeController', ['$routeParams', 'invoiceService', 'vismaService', '$uibModal', '$log', function ($routeParams, invoiceService, vismaService, $uibModal, $log) {
    var vm = this;
    var vismaDebitAccount = {
        catogory: '',
        account: ''
    }
    var vismaCreditAccount = {
        catogory: '',
        account: ''
    }

     vm.openVismaAccModal = function (accountType) {
    console.log('hi before')
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'accountPopup.html',
        controller: 'vismaAccController as vm'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedAccount) {
        if (accountType === 'debit') {
            vm.vismaAccEntries[0].debitAccNo = selectedAccount.account.No;
        }

        if (accountType === 'credit') {
            vm.vismaAccEntries[0].creditAccNo = selectedAccount.account.No;
        }
        
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });

}

}]);
```

```js
app.controller('vismaAccController', ['vismaService', '$uibModalInstance', function (vismaService, $uibModalInstance) {

    var vm = this;
    var selectedAcc = {
        category: '',
        account: ''
    };

    Init();

    function Init() {
        getVismaAccData();
    }

    vm.tabChange = function (e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName === 'A') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    vm.rowSelect = function (index, debitAcc, flag) {

        selectedAcc.category = flag;
        selectedAcc.account = debitAcc;

    }

    vm.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close(selectedAcc);
    };

    vm.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    function getVismaAccData() {
        var errors = [];
        vismaService.getSuppliers().then(function (data) {
            vm.vismaSuppliers = data;
        },
            function (errorMsg) {
                errors.push('<li>' + errorMsg + '</li>');
                vm.savedSuccessfully = false;
            });

        vismaService.getCustomers()
            .then(function (data) {
                vm.vismaCustomers = data;
            },
            function (errorMsg) {
                errors.push('<li>' + errorMsg + '</li>');
                vm.savedSuccessfully = false;
            });

        vismaService.getGeneralLedger()
            .then(function (data) {
                vm.vismaGL = data;
            },
            function (errorMsg) {
                errors.push('<li>' + errorMsg + '</li>');
                vm.savedSuccessfully = false;
            });

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            vm.message = errors.join(' ');
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I don't see ng-model to input.

Comment: vm.vismaDebitAccount expect to update. it is passing as parameter to vm.openVismaAccModal method when popup bind to button ng-click.       <div><input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Pick Up" ng-click="vm.openVismaAccModal(vm.vismaDebitAccount)" /></div>

Comment: then where is code of row selection handler?

Comment: i update the code please look at

Comment: i want to rather than pass 'credit' or 'debit' as parameter. pass actual model variable to update